# LinkedIn Company Profile Plugin not displaying

Tags: linkedin-api

Occasionally, the LinkedIn company profile plugin (https://developer.linkedin.com/plugins/company-profile) refuses to display on our webpage giving the following error:

```
Refused to display in frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame- VM35 profile:1 ancestors 'self'".
```

Sometimes it displays and sometimes it does not, with no pattern I could discern.

Does anyone know what might be causing this? Also I would love to get LinkedIn's input as they directed me here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, the LinkedIn company profile plugin is not supported anymore since a few days ago.

This does not directly answer your question, but I would not recommend to spend too much time on trying to troubleshoot your specific problem, as I assume that it will be discontinued at the same time as the v1 of the API, i.e. on March 1, 2019.